# typescript use same type with different names to two different functions

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I have Prices `type` like this

```js
interface Prices {
  currentPrice: number;
  totalPrice: number;
}
```

- I want to use Prices `type` in some other functions which have different name property.

```js
const percentage = ({ currentPrice: actual, totalPrice: total }: Prices): string => {
   // do something...
};

const CalculatePercentage = ({ Percentage: percent, totalPrice: total }: Prices): number => { // Here this have different property name - would be error
  // do something...
};
```

Comment: `Prices & { Percentage: number }`? What is the scope of it, though? (assuming typeof Percentage is number)

Comment: yes, types are same but different property names @briosheje

Comment: You can omit `currentPrice` and add `Percentage`. `Omit<Prices, 'currentPrice'> & {Percentage:Prices['currentPrice']}`

Comment: Maybe you want to try nullable fields `interface Prices {
  currentPrice?: number;
  percentage?: number;
  totalPrice: number;
}`

Comment: any shorter version for this `Omit<Prices, 'currentPrice'> & {Percentage:Prices['currentPrice']}` seems same or longer than `{ percentage: number, totalPrice: number }`